# Pulseaudio and networking

Tags: networking, pulseaudio

I have a websocket server that was working until I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

and then it would no longer get connections from my webapp. On the webapp side it was get connection refused.

As soon as I did a:

```
$ killall pulseaudio
```

and restarted the websocket server the webapp was able to connect again.

After restarting pulseaudio I tried to connect the webapp and the websocket server through a different port and it still failed.

I don't get it. What is going on here?